# calcOpticalFlowPyrLK horizontal and vertical flow u,v

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I need to get the u,v components so that I can compute an avoidance strategy of obstacles for blind people.
I will divide the frame into 2 halves and sum up the flow components u+v in them the avoidance strategy will be that the blind person will move away from the half that has the higher value of flow .

The function calcOpticalFlowPyrLK in opencv returns the position of the points in the new frame however I need the u and v components.
How can that be achieved. And also is there an avoidance strategy that I can use better than this one using only an RGB camera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for dividing for the u and v components, I suggest doing a simple subtraction of point coordinates before and after translation. You can try to speed it up by for example putting all the points into 2 channel matrices and subtracting matrices from each other.

As for a better way [here](http://intel-research.net/Publications/Pittsburgh/092620050634_312.pdf) is an article I based my masters thesis on. There is a trick in it using amount of optical flow for obstacle detection.